# AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'index'

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, python-3.7

I'm converting my Python2.x to Python3.x code and it's throwing this error:

```
Python 3.7.8 (default, Jun 29 2020, 05:46:05) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> config_order = {
...                     'groups.jinja2': 0 ,
...                     'system.jinja2': 1 ,
...                     'interfaces.jinja2': 2,
...                     'chassis.jinja2': 3 ,
...                     'snmp.jinja2': 4 ,
...                     'routing-options.jinja2': 5 ,
...                     'policy-options.jinja2': 6 ,
...                     'security.jinja2': 7 ,
...                     'routing-instances.jinja2': 8
...         }
>>> template = config_order.keys()[config_order.values().index(element)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'index'
>>>
```

How do I convert my dictionary values to a list so I can use 'index' function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Find key by value in Python dictionary

You need to turn `config_order.keys()` and `config_order.values()` into list:

```
list(config_order.keys())[list(config_order.values()).index(element)]
```

But that solution is hard to read. Consider this one instead:

```
next(k for k, v in config_order.items() if v == element)
```

Or if you want it fault-tolerant/default value:

```
next((k for k, v in config_order.items() if v == 10), None)
```

---

#### Example:

```
next(k for k, v in config_order.items() if v == 7)
```

**Output:**

> `'security.jinja2'`

```
next((k for k, v in config_order.items() if v == 70), 'default')
```

**Output:**

> `'default'`